# Rigging a Watt's Linkage Assembly

Tags: armature

I am trying to rig a [Watt's linkage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watt%27s_linkage) suspension assembly. Here is a screenshot:
[image: Armature of a Watt's linkage]

Bones A and B have a Track To constraint that makes them follow bones E and F, respectively, which are parented to bone G. Bones C and D should follow along as bones A and B rotate, attached to A and B and setting limits to the rotation. I haven't been able to make that happen. 
[image: Rotating action driven by bone G]
Could this be made to work using inverse kinematics? Or would it be better to assign physics behavior to meshes that represent the parts of the mechanical assembly?

Comment: Can you add a bit of info on how you intend to animate this rig (Is bone g effectively the control)?

Comment: You would move bone G, and it would pull along bones E and F. Bones A and B would rotate to follow E and F, and C and D would be forced to follow along as A and B rotate. The tips of A and C must remain attached to each other, and the same for B and D. C and D must also remain attached to one another. C and D are free to rotate to allow movement. G, E and F may move freely in relation to the other bones- they only generate movement, and it is the attachments of the other bones to one another that control the movement. I can't get C and D to follow along.